# Better way of uploading csv file to sql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please help me improve my code. I have this html form to select a .csv file extension only, to upload it in my sql database. How can I improve this? like make the button not clickable if there is no file chosen.

```
<form class="ui input" enctype="multipart/form-data" method = "POST" role = "form">
  <input type = "file" name ="file" id="file" size = "150">
  <button class="ui small red button" type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default" name ="submit"  value = "submit">Upload CSV</button> 
</form>
```

Then this is my php code to upload the csv, How can I make a popup message saying "your file is uploading please wait" and "finished uploading". And my problem here is that the headers of my csv file is also uploaded how can I exclude the first row of my csv?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'jeremy_db';

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die ('Could not' .mysqli_error($con));

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $c = 0;

    while(($csvdata = fgetcsv($handle,1000,","))!== FALSE){
        $sha1 = $csvdata[0];
        $vsdt = $csvdata[1];
        $trendx  = $csvdata[2];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO jeremy_table_trend (sha1,vsdt,trendx) VALUES ('$sha1','$vsdt','$trendx')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con , $sql);

        $c = $c+1;
    }
    if($query){
        echo "SABRE";
    }
    else { 
        echo "SLAM";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm using php 7 guys, any suggestions?

Comment: you could start by using prepared statements - you're open to SQL injection atm

Answer (score 0):

Initially you can keep the submit button disable. Then oclick to input file you can call a js function which will validate file extension and will enable the submit button accordingly.

For showing message -  you can write a javascript function onclick to submit button.

For processing big file on fly this is not a good practice. It will be timed out to execute all queries(number of queries = number of rows in csv). You can do this by following below steps -

1. First upload the csv file to the server
2. Create an stored procedure(pass the uploaded file path to this procedure) which will load the csv file into the database. You can get help to load file here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html
3. For excluding header you will get instruction in above link

Comment: could you help me? I'm just starting to learn php. What should I change here